# Computing $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}Pr(X_n=0)$ for r.v $X_n$ using matrices and Markov Chains.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

There are three coins on the table showing "Heads". Every round, Danny comes and turns a coin upside down: the left one with probability of $1\over 2$, the middle with probability of $1\over 3$ and the right with probability of $1\over 3$. Let $X_n$ be the number of coins showing "Heads" after $n$ rounds. Find $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}Pr(X_n=0)$.

What I did so far is drawing a graph of 8 events, and arriving at a symmetric, stochastic matrix, that is: $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&{1\over 6}&{1\over 3}&{1\over 2}&0&0&0&0\\{1\over 6}&0&0&0&{1\over 3}&{1\over 2}&0&0\\{1\over 3}&0&0&0&{1\over 6}&0&{1\over 2}&0\\{1\over 2}&0&0&0&0&{1\over 6}&{1\over 3}&0\\0&{1\over 3}&{1\over 6}&0&0&0&0&{1\over 2}\\0&{1\over 2}&0&{1\over 6}&0&0&0&{1\over 3}\\0&0&{1\over 2}&{1\over 3}&0&0&0&{1\over 6}\\0&0&0&0&{1\over 2}&{1\over 3}&{1\over 6}&0 \end{pmatrix}$

I am to compute, I guess, $\mu A^n$ where $\mu=(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$, but I can't possible do this with this matrix. I thought of diagonalizing it by eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I think it is too complex as well. Maybe I am wrong and I don't have to look for $\mu A^n$. What can I do, or what do I better do to answer this question? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Last coordinate of your vector of states contains probability that all the coins are tails. You start with the vector [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] - with probability 1 all the coins are heads. You actually don't need to compute the whole eigenvector decomposition of your matrix. Your principal eigenvalue will be 1 (cause it's a stochastic matrix, all its eigenvalues are <=1), so upon taking the matrix to the power of n $.99^n<<1^n$, so only principal eigenvalue and eigenvector matter. You need to find the principal eigenvector by just solving $Av=Iv$ and I expect its last coordinate to be 0.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up. Let the game begin.

Comment: So I have a diagonal matrix and the vector of initial state. Where does the part referring the last coordinate, i.e, the state in which all are tails, take action?

Comment: I am lost a bit right now...What do I do with the eigenvector? How do I know how many times $1$ shows up on the diagonal? Should I just be using the diagonalized matrix?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm calculating eigenvector decomposition in python. You can compute the main eigenvector (i.e. the eigenvector that corresponds to eigenvalue 1) and its last coordinate should be 0 - that's the probability  of all tails after infinite number of rounds.

Comment: Meitar, are you sure, you haven't made a mistake? Your matrix is not symmetric. You have 1/3 and 1/2 in the second line not symmetric to 1/3 and 1/6! Thus eigenvectors are not real-valued, but complex.

Comment: I checking it again...
I am still not sure if I am to diagonalize it fully or not. What if it even not diagonalizeable?

Comment: The second line equals the second column doesn't it?

Comment: It is fully diagonalizable. I've already calculated the diagonal matrix: it is (array([ -1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
          1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -6.66666667e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          6.66666667e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -3.33333333e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          3.33333333e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          7.36608398e-18 +1.52386248e-17j,
          7.36608398e-18 -1.52386248e-17j]) i.e. [-1,1,-2/3,2/3, -1/3, 1/3, 0, 0] - the eigenvalues.

Comment: I mean, $A_{5,3}=A_{3,5}$ or not? In your case they are different.

Comment: They are both ${1\over 6}$...

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad.

Comment: So, diagonal values of diagonal matrix are [-1,1,-2/3,2/3, -1/3, 1/3, 0, 0]

Comment: So I will have to find all eigenvalues I suppose...

Comment: Meitar, diagonal values of diagonal matrix ARE eigenvalues! That's the whole point.

Comment: I mean, that I had to compute it all to begin with.

Comment: Well, we already knew without computation that 1 is principal eigenvalue. We should've checked whether  -1 is principal eigenvalue, too or not (this can be done manually, without computer). Corresponding eigenvectors can be found manually, too. As the  matrix is symmetric, its eigenvectors are orthogonal, so you don't need computer to find the coefficients of these 2 eigenvectors as well - they are just dot product of initial state vector and each main eigenvector. So, in this case computer is not necessary, by brain is just being rusty.

Comment: couldn't it also be smaller than -1?
And finally- how do I know where $1$ and $-1$ are on the diagonal?

Comment: You can put them in arbitrary order. Eigenvalue's absolute value can't be larger than 1 for stochastic matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which state does each row and column of the Markov Chain represents.

However, you already have the transition matrix, which is irreducible and aperiodic, so you just need to solve the equation

$\pi P = \pi$

where $\pi$ is a row vector, corresponding to each row of the matrix, then

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n=0)=\pi_{TTT}$

You should take some time to read the wikipedia page on Markov chains carefully.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to find the stationary distribution?

Comment: @Meitar that is certainly easier than calculating matrix exponentials... Note that $\pi^T$ is just the eigenvector of $P^T$ with eigenvalue 1 and the entries adds up to one. Perron-Frobenius theorem says the dimension of the eigenspace is 1, so there will only be a unqiue one.

Comment: The matrix limit will tend to a limiting matrix $\Pi$ such that each row of $\Pi$ is just $\pi$...

and oh the limit is independent of where you start...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: found an error, fixed.

Hm, seems that I lied to you. We have 2 principal eigenvalues here, 1 and -1.

Here's the output of python (check that I'm not mistaken in the matrix):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.linalg.eig(numpy.array([[0, 1.0/6, 1.0/3, 1.0/2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1.0/6, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/3, 1.0/2, 0, 0], [1.0/3, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/6, 0, 1.0/2, 0], [1.0/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/6, 1.0/3, 0], [0, 1.0/3, 1.0/6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/2], [0, 1.0/2, 0, 1.0/6, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/3], [0, 0, 1.0/2, 1.0/3, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0/2, 1.0/3, 1.0/6, 0]]))

(array([ -1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
          1.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -6.66666667e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          6.66666667e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -3.33333333e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          3.33333333e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,
          7.36608398e-18 +1.52386248e-17j,
          7.36608398e-18 -1.52386248e-17j]),
array([[ 0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.46605803 -2.20397973e-18j,  0.46605803 +2.20397973e-18j],
   [-0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.05343861 -1.73015110e-01j,  0.05343861 +1.73015110e-01j],
   [-0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.05343861 -1.73015110e-01j,  0.05343861 +1.73015110e-01j],
   [-0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.05343861 +1.73015110e-01j, -0.05343861 -1.73015110e-01j],
   [ 0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.46605803 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.46605803 +0.00000000e+00j],
   [ 0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.46605803 -8.19250267e-18j, -0.46605803 +8.19250267e-18j],
   [ 0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.46605803 -1.24344437e-17j, -0.46605803 +1.24344437e-17j],
   [-0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j, -0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,  0.35355339 +0.00000000e+00j,
    -0.05343861 +1.73015110e-01j, -0.05343861 -1.73015110e-01j]]))
```

The first array in the output is the array of eigenvalues, the second - eigenvectors in corresponding order.

So, $A^n\cdot w=c_1 \lambda_1^n v_1+c2 \lambda_2^n v_2+...+c_8 \lambda_8^n v_8$, where $A$ is your matrix, $w$ is your initial vector of states, $v_1..v_8$ are eigenvectors, $\lambda_1 .. \lambda_8$ are eigenvalues and $c_1..c_8$ are coefficients of decomposition of your initial vector $w$ into eigenvectors. When you take eigenvalue to large powers, e.g. 1000, only eigenvalues with largest absolute value remain meaningful, all the other vanish (cause $0.99^1000<<1^1000$).

In our case only eigenvalues 1 and -1 remain. This means that any initial vector after large number of steps will be converted to main eigenvector(-s).

If I'm not mistaken, Python strangely returns eigenvectors in transposed form. So, main eigenvectors are [0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, -0.35] for eigenvalue 1 and [-0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35] for -1.

We also need to find coefficients of decomposition $c_1$ and $c_2$ corresponding to eigenvalues 1 and -1 and after that I expect them to nullify each other's last coordinate.

Ok, I found the quotients of decomposition $c_1..c_8$. They are

```
>>> numpy.linalg.solve(eigenvectors, [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
array([ 0.35355339 +3.11217606e-17j, -0.35355339 -6.72744505e-17j,
   -0.35355339 -1.64734712e-17j, -0.35355339 +9.12252483e-17j,
    0.35355339 +7.19520689e-18j,  0.35355339 -6.92044883e-18j,
    0.35355339 -2.28058319e-17j, -0.35355339 -1.17581670e-17j])
```

So, our eigenvalues 1 and -1 have inverse quotients 0.35 and -0.35.

Thus, probability of all-tails at infinity jumps between 0 for even number of tosses and 0.35*0.7 for odd.

Comment: I'm seeing it the other way around, that is 0 for even tosses and about 0.35*0.7 for odd tosses just multiplying it out a million times.  Also states states HTT, THT, and THH are non-zero for even, and 0 for odd, while HHT, HTH, and THH are non-zero for odd and 0 for even.  HHH is always non-zero.